# Voice Recording Has Lower Decibels Than "Silent" Recording

Tags: naudio, audacity

I have looked at a number of articles on detecting silence in a recording using NAudio. But, I ran into a snag.  I am now looking into using the more complex silence detection methods such as Fourier Transform.  In the meantime, perhaps someone can shed some light on the problem I have run into.

I wrote a program in C# using NAudio to detect silence in a WAV file.  I have a sample dictation file that I used to test it and it works fine.

As a further test, I used Audacity to create a Wav file that has 1 minute of silence in it using the Noise Reduction feature. When I listen to it, I don't hear sound.  When I run my program on it, the lowest decibel reading is higher than the lowest decibel reading in the dictation file. I'm wondering why because this concerns me that there might be dictation files that have silence in them that I cannot detect.

Comment: Perhaps there are sounds in the recording at frequencies too high (or too low) for your speakers to produce (and/or for your ears to hear) but that are nonetheless being detected by your algorithm?  If so, you might want to use a band-pass EQ (or etc) to mask those frequencies out of the audio before analyzing it.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a Wav file that has 1 minute of silence in it using the Noise Reduction feature"? Did you record anything with a microphone? Did you use an existing audio file?

Comment: I just clicked the record button in Audacity and let it record with no speech for a little over a minute.  Then I used the Noise Reduction feature in Audacity to reduce the noise in it.  There was a low hum in it.  The resulting recording showed a straight line on the graph.